# Backup filtered search email keeping folder structure

Tags: backup, email

How can I backup an email account keeping the email folder structure?

I mean for instance:
I want to backup all the emails older than 2 years however I want to keep the folder structure that I have on my email accounts... For instance, I have a folder for each client...

Comment: Apple's Time Machine does this.